# Mailslot with string

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, mailslot

I need to make a message concating various parts. So I used ostringstream. Now I have a std::string or a const * char to send by mailslot.
I have tryed many ways to do it but every time I receive wrong messages.
I would like to know a solution to send messages by mailslot and receive it and show it by console.

My code to generate and send the mail is:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "RE" << "01" << "01:01:02.350" << "REMOTA 01 - MSG DESCARTADA";
    std::string alarm = oss.str();

    const char *a = alarm.c_str();
ASSERT(WriteFile(hMailslot, &a, strlen(a), &dwBytesSent, NULL),
```

"Impossible to sent message.");

and to receive the message is:

```
char alarm[42];
            DWORD bytesRead;
            ASSERT(ReadFile(hMailslot, &alarm, strlen(alarm), &bytesRead, NULL), 
                "Impossible to read file. ERROR: " << GetLastError());
```

I would like to use a std::cout or a printf to read this mensage.

Regards,
Leandro Lima

Comment: You forgot the semicolon `;` at line 42 of your code

Comment: What have you done so far? What error messages are you getting? Show us the code that is generating the errors. We won't write it for you from scratch, this isn't rentacoder!!

Comment: It's not safe to store the result of `c_str()` like that.

Comment: Don't put "working" code inside asserts. When compiled for release, asserts are not included in the produced code and your "working" code is therefore eliminated.

Comment: So, if is not safe to use it like that, how to do?

Comment: The Assert code is mine. I made the macro to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the result of c_str() is safe as long as the string objects are not modified, but that's beside the point.  The problem is you are passing the address of a pointer to a string instead of simply a pointer to a string.  Change &a and &alarm to just a and alarm.